# Finding MIN of Multiple Columns without blanks

Tags: powerbi

I have a table with 5 columns. I want to have a 6th column that gives the minimum from the first 5 line by line but some the 5 columns have blank entries so my min column picks these up as the minimum. How can I get the minimum I want? For example

If my numbers are

2,3,5,Blank,1

I want 1, not Blank.

Comment: I'm triyng to found the second min. Do you know how to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/MIN-with-Multiple-Columns/m-p/369307) as a DAX Column (not measure):

```
Min = 
VAR temp = { 'Data'[Column1], 'Data'[Column2], 'Data'[Column3], 'Data'[Column4], 'Data'[Column5] }
RETURN
    MINX ( Temp, [Value] )
```

[image: Power BI]